# Disable seeking in Android MediaController

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a video player using Android MediaPlayer and VideoView. I would like to disable the seek thumb so that users are not able to skip around in a video.

Users should only be able to pause/play the video and nothing more. I've been able to remove the forward and back buttons using "MediaController(this,false)". I am also able to completely remove all controls using ".setMediaController(null)", but I have not been able to leave the play/pause buttons and the seekbar, but disable changing positions of the video by dragging the seekbar thumb.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl` interface, return `false` from the `canSeekBackward()` and `canSeekForward()` methods. You can also have the `seekTo(int pos)` method simply do nothing at all. That should fix it.